# Vim behaving strange ,whenever i reach a certain line,it starts to highlight it and i get an error in most programs

Tags: vim, terminal, ubuntu-16.04, text-editor, vi

i am not sure what is causing this, going back and forth in insert mode,i sometime get into some strange situation where after a number of characters written on a line, vim start highlighting part of that line.
I tried to delete that line and and start again but when it reaches that points,it starts again highlighting for no obvious reasons.
i suspect that there might be some hidden character but i am not sure how to check it.
[image]

whenever i reach the part after username value, it highlights.
I deleted the line and started to type after the end of the previous line but as soon as i reach that part,it starts to highlight again.
I close the file and reopen it again,that part is still highlighted.

whenever i try to mount my samba sever,it say parse error on that line and i also remember that it use to happens in python,it also caused me problems that i had to use gedit to delete and write another line.
This time, i am connecting to a server,therefore it won't be easy for me to use gedit to correct this problem and i also think its not a lasting answer.
I tried to search but all the question i`ve seen are not related to this or i am don't know the right question to look for,that is why i am formulating it here the best that i can.
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
content of my vimrc

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

only pathogen  is installed

Comment: Unfortunaly nobody will be able to help you without your `.vimrc` and the list of installed plugin (if not visibile in the vimrc). But for the very first step, you should start vim without any plugins and settings with `vim -u NONE` and have a look if it happens there too

Comment: thank you very much,starting vim disabled the plugins but i still get the error is still the same, i added my vimrc content

Comment: Is it some `:set nohlsearch` issue?

Comment: @Nishant, i tried it too,it did not work, i am litterary deleting the line,close the file,reopen again ,when i arrive to that point,it starts  that pseudo highlight

Comment: if this is also happening without plugins and settings, it is most likely a syntax error. Since I have the same behaviour in my vim, i bet Thomas Dickey is right!

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo,he was right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/etc/fstab` file has a spurious blank before **`password`** (treated as a field separator), and vim's syntax highlighting flags that as a syntax error.

Comment: you were right,it was due to space between tokens, once you start writing comma separated fields, you can no longer write fields separated with space!

Comment: **Fields** in /etc/fstab are separated by blanks, but fields can have multiple **options** -- separated by commas.